# Умножить параметр FastReport на определенное число

Tags: fastreport

в отчете Fastreport есть параметр, который нужно умножить на число 15. Как это сделать?
Например, параметр `[Доход]`, нужно умножить на 15. Компилятор ругается на подобное: `[Доход*15]`

Comment: Сейчас нету FR под рукой. Попробуйте `[<Доход>*15]`, `[FloatToStr(<Доход>*15)]`, `[Get('Доход')*15]` или подобную комбинацию. Трюк в том, что квадратные скобки в поле отчета обозначают переход к скриптовой части, а в ней угловые - получение параметра. Что-то в этом роде, вобщем.

Comment: @Kromster , к сожалению, ничего из этого не сработало. Выдает исключение "недопустимый термин "<"". А во втором случае: превышен лимит символов

Comment: Попробуйте `[]` вместо `<>`. Точно помню, что это подобным образом решалось. Если никак, то из скрипта устанавливать значение полю на `OnData`.

Comment: @Kromster Да! Спасибо! [[Parametr]*15]

Comment: @Kromster только за. А не подскажите, как можно получить значение с ячейки таблицы? Например с Cell1 получить значение и сложить его с Cell2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107591/discussion-between---and-kromster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Сейчас нету FR под рукой.*

Попробуйте `[[Доход]*15]`. Трюк в том, что квадратные скобки в поле отчета обозначают переход к скриптовой части, а в ней вторые квадратные - получение параметра в скрипте (вместо `<>`, почему-то).

Кроме простого умножения, вы можете делать и другие, более простые и более сложные вещи, типа сложения, вызова функций и т.п. Главное чтобы это было 1 выражением, "в 1 строке".